# Resolve Promise within onclick

Tags: javascript, promise

I am trying to get the below code working. The first function (prepareNewCard) creates a div in the webpage, so I use a promise to make sure the next function (getSearchTerm) is executed only once the div is created.
getSearchTerm is intended to resolve with the search term from the previously created div. To test this I am trying to console.log the search term. However, the search term is logged as null, however the console.log("here") within the function works as expected. It seems to me that the promise is resolving before the .onclick, but I do not understand how this could happen.

Here is code for the two functions

```
function prepareNewCard() {
    //Most of this not relevant to the question, creating the div
    var currentCard = document.createElement("div");
    currentCard.className += " card";
    currentCard.className += " currentCard";
    var currentSearch = document.createElement("input");
    currentSearch.className += " searchInput";
    currentSearch.placeholder += "Enter a search term...";
    var searchButton = document.createElement("button");
    searchButton.className += " searchButton";

    //Create the card to be searched                                                    
    currentCard.appendChild(currentSearch);
    currentCard.appendChild(searchButton);

    //Add this card to the main div                                                     
    const searchResultsArea = document.getElementById("searchResults");

    //The promise being returned
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
            currentCards = document.getElementById(".currentCard");
            if (currentCards === null) {
                searchResultsArea.appendChild(currentCard);
                resolve(currentCard);
            } else {
                reject('Use your current card before creating a new one');
            }
        });
}

function getSearchTerm(currentCard) {
    currentSearchBar = currentCard.querySelector(".searchInput");
    currentSearchButton = currentCard.querySelector(".searchButton");

    currentSearchButton.onclick = function() {
        return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
                var currentSearchInput = currentSearchBar.value;
                if (currentSearchInput !== null) {
                    resolve(currentSearchInput);
                    console.log("here");
                } else {
                    reject("Please input search term");
                }
            });
    }
}
```

The code that is calling these functions is here

```
    newCardButton.onclick = function() {
        prepareNewCard()
        .then(function(currentCard) {
                getSearchTerm(currentCard)
                .then(function(searchTerm) {
                     console.log(searchTerm)
                })  
                .catch(function(error) {
                    console.log(error)
                });
        })
        .catch(function(error) {
                console.log(error);
        });
    }
```

Is this not possible with javascript promises? I have tried a number of configurations for the promise .then functions and none seem to work. Thanks in advance!

EDIT:

Here is another version done without promises.

```
function prepareNewCard() {
    //Same code above to create div
    const searchResultsArea = document.getElementById("searchResults");
    searchResultsArea.appendChild(currentCard);
    return currentCard;
}

function getSearchTerm(currentCard) {
    currentSearchBar = currentCard.querySelector(".searchInput");
    currentSearchButton = currentCard.querySelector(".searchButton");

    currentSearchButton.onclick = function() {
    console.log("TEST");
    return currentSearchBar.value;
}
```

```
    let currentCard;
    let currentSearchTerm;
    newCardButton.onclick = function() {
    currentCard = prepareNewCard();
    currentSearchTerm = getSearchTerm(currentCard);
    console.log(currentSearchTerm);
}
```

The console about for the above code looks like:

Click newcardbutton and immediately get 'undefined' in response to console.log(currentSearchTerm). 
Then, when clicking the searchButton in the dynamically create div console prints "TEST" and nothing else.

Comment: DOM functions are synchronous are they not? I don't think there is a reason to use promises here.

Comment: I just tried it without promises, and while I think you are correct (everything still works same as before), it doesn't avoid the problem of logging an undefined for the search term before I ever click the search button.

Comment: Could you update your question with the non-promise code so we are looking at the same thing? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you're returning a promise from the `onclick` handler function, not from `getSearchTerm` and it doesn't return anything, so it should be:

```js
function getSearchTerm(currentCard) {
    currentSearchBar = currentCard.querySelector(".searchInput");
    currentSearchButton = currentCard.querySelector(".searchButton");

    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
          currentSearchButton.onclick = function() {
                var currentSearchInput = currentSearchBar.value;
                if (currentSearchInput !== null) {
                    resolve(currentSearchInput);
                    console.log("here");
                } else {
                    reject("Please input search term");
                }
          }
     });
}
```

Also, returning a promise from `prepareNewCard` is completely unnecessary as it's synchronous, instead, just return the value or throw the error:

```js
currentCards = document.getElementById(".currentCard");
if (currentCards === null) {
    searchResultsArea.appendChild(currentCard);
    return currentCard;
} else {
    throw 'Use your current card before creating a new one';
}
```